# jquery particle generator

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have made a particle generator with Jquery it works fine but it is kinda a CPU hog. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
function particles() {

$.each($('.particles'), function () {
    if ($(this).css("opacity") == 0) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

var particleSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);

var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 3000);
var distance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 200);
var fallOffSpeed = speed / 2;
var fallOff = distance + distance / 2;

$('body').prepend($($('<div>', {
    "class" : "particles",
    "height": particleSize,
    "width": particleSize
}).css({
    "background-color": "red",
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Math.floor(Math.random() * 39),
    "z-index": "-1"
}).animate({
    "left": distance
}, speed, 'linear').animate({
    "left": fallOff,
    "opacity" : "0"
}, fallOffSpeed, 'linear')));

setTimeout(particles, 1000);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a very small [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/Glideh/jquery.particles.burst) for generating particles from an element ([demo](http://pburst.gprod.net/))

My plugin also takes advantage of CSS3 for the animation thanks to `jquery.animate-enhanced`

(You should be able to use canvas in IE with [this kind of thing](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/))

Comment: Your fiddle demo didn't work on github but the canvas in explorer is cool thx.

Comment: The demo is now updated and hosted in a dedicated location

Answer (score 2):

Use vanilla JavaScript in a canvas element and it will fly.

eg: http://www.ferretarmy.com/files/canvas/canvasParticle/canvasParticle2.html